# Calculating the threshold of a set of values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics, threshold

**Question:**

The context of this question is actually finance, however the question itself is a statistical issue.

Suppose I have the following expression:

$$\rho = \frac{2\bar{x}}{(s^*_x)^2}+1 .......... (1)$$

where

$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} x_t$

$(s^*_x)^2 = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T (x_t - \bar{x})^2$

Assume $T$ is some fixed constant. Note: $T$ is just the total number of observations of $x_t$.

I have data on $x_t$ for each 'entity' (here an entity just simply refers to a firm/company). In total, I have 2228 entities and for each entity I have $T$ observations of $x_t$.

For each entity, I substitute the $T$ observations of $x_t$ into Eqn. $(1)$ and obtain a value for $\rho$. Thus in total, I have 2228 values of $\rho$.

Now, a large value of $\rho$ means the entity is "bad" and a small value of $\rho$ means the entity is "good". However, the problem is how large does a value of $\rho$ have to be in order to classify an entity as "bad"? That is, what is the threshold such that if $\rho$ exceeds the threshold value, then we can classify the entity as "bad"?

For example, let's say the threshold is $400$, if entity A had a $\rho = 300$ while entity B had a $\rho = 1000$, then entity A is "good" while entity B is "bad".

---

**My attempts so far:**

My first attempt was to try get data on an entity that is known to be "bad" and then calculate its $\rho$ and use this value as the threshold. The problem is that I cannot obtain data on "bad" entities.

For my next attempt, I obtained the empirical distribution by applying a kernel density estimator on the 2228 values of $\rho$. Then I calculate the 99th percentile (for robustness, I also calculated the 97.5th and 95th percentile) of this pooled distribution and use this value as the threshold. However, the main critique is that this is too arbitrary and there is not enough rationale for using this method.

---

**Queries:**

So I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how what statistical/mathematical techniques/methods I can apply to derive appropriate thresholds for $\rho$. Currently, I really have no idea on what tools are available for this problem.

Comment: See my comments on the math stack page version of this.